# Is it right to use comma before "here"?

Tags: adverbs, commas, sentence-ends

> Members of parliament can criticize other members, here.

Note the comma after *members* and before *here*.

In this particular case, is it okay? Or should the comma not be there?

Comment: There is a growing acceptance of the use of commas to show where pauses occur / are wished to occur in spoken English. John Lawler might even say that that's their _only_ role. The unmarked form would not include the comma, but if 'here' is emphasised (as your bolding indicates), a pause to add more emphasis might well be valid, and a comma used to show this in the written form. Though the example seems a little strange, and a dash might be preferred.

Comment: @EdwinA: Yes, I can imagine the speaker of this sentence pausing pregnantly & stressing laboriously or "toryously" the ultimate utterance "**here!**" = "_MPs can criticize other MPs here (House of Commons?), in this place, but not elsewhere, specifically not in press conferences or other public venues_".

Comment: Taking liberalities.

Comment: Okay. So a comma is not a wrong thing there!!

Comment: Oh, no! We spend half our time weeding out misplaced commas. Must we now encourage them? The sample sentence, if anything, screamed for another "here" at the end:
    Members of Parliament can criticize other members, here here!

Comment: If the intention is to make "here" mean "here but not elsewhere", then I don't think a comma does the job; I'd use words.

Answer (score 1):

The comma is there to add emphasis. It *also* indicates where a pause might occur in speech, but the pause is as a result of the comma, not the other way around. So, one would pause there for the emphasis that the comma indicates. Despite what some of us may have been taught at school, punctuation should not be used to indicate pauses per se (except in representing how something was actually said, eg, in creative writing or transcription).

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the context:

"This is our internal message board. Members of parliament can criticize other members here." would be used without a comma. (i.e. "*This* is the place to do this.")
I would only set a comma if the sentence were to convey: "Members of parliament can criticize other members, here." - but not elsewhere. (i.e. "*Only* this is the place to do this.")

I don't know of any directly applicable grammatical rule for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that in certain situations, a comma is required both before and after the word 'here.' I wouldn't normally write with 'here' after a subject, but in conversation, the words are often spoken.

See these two examples:

John, here, has an important question. (This looks correct with commas.)
John here has an important question.   (This looks incorrect.)

John, here, was seen going into that building earlier. (This looks correct.)
John here was seen going into that building earlier.   (This looks incorrect.)

I cannot find any resource telling me whether or not this is correct, but I think the use of the word 'here' (without being isolated with commas) looks out of place. Thoughts?

Comment: I think "John here, ..." looks even better. But this is a new question, so please ask it using the big button on the main page. This will likely get removed for that reason. Please take the [Tour] to familiarize yourself with this platform. Welcome to ELU! :)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/421047)

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how you want to use it.
According to Wiktionary, "here" is an adverb, which is probably what you want.
... No.
Likewise, you wouldn't say

> I bake cakes, well.

However, if you have "here" as an interjection, it'd be okay.
As in

> Come look! Here!

Comment: I don't think that's the usage the OP is referring to. The original sentence seems to refer deictically to a place where MPs can criticise each other.